# The environment texture and material output - Principled BDSF nodes are connected but do not show up in object view. Blender 2.9

Tags: materials

I think my Blender is broken because I've tried everything I could source from the internet and spent hours just exploring blender.

I have 2 problems but I'll start with the environment texture. In the shade editor, I connected the Environment Texture (I uploaded a jpg image) to the Background and to the World Output. I also tried connecting the Environment Texture just to the World Output. I checked the box for "USE NODES" and in the World Properties it says the nodes are connected and yet my jpg isn't displayed. It is still the viewport display color. In the viewport drop down I made sure that WOLRD is selected. I even connected the nodes in the Shading tab, still nothing. (photos below)

The other problem I have is similar but it's for the material output. In the shade editor, I connected the Principled BDSF to the material output, checked the nodes are connected properly and nothing is working. The only way I can change my material is by disconnecting the nodes and using the Material Properties in the editors panel (there are only 3... metallic, specular, roughness).

I've googled, read forums, restarted my computer, and nothing has worked. Am I missing something or should I throw my computer away?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file? upload and share the link it will give you in the URL field: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: For the world settings: Looking at your screenshot I can see your _3D Viewport Shading_ set to _Solid_ in the top picture and _Material Preview_ in the bottom pic. None of those views shows the background image (by default). If you want to see it there, you have to either use _Rendered_ view or change the _Shading_ options to _Scene World_ in _Material Preview_. In _Solid_ view it will only display a color.

Comment: For the material: if the second screenshot is supposed to show the object's material, then you have to set the _Shader Editor_ mode to _Object_, yours is set to _World_. In this case you can only edit the world material, not the object's material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upper screenshot, you are in solid mode - you won't see materials in that mode. In the lower screenshot, your are in Material preview, here you won't see any World material by default.

But as Gordon mentioned, you can see the world material by checking "Scene world" here:

[image]

Press the right button here for rendered view: [image]

then you will see both: material for objects and your world material.

Comment: You can see the _World_ material in _Material Preview_, if you set the _Shading_ option to _Scene World_.

Comment: Thank you, i updated my answer